# Foreach takes long time using SMO

Tags: sql-server, foreach, smo

I have a method (old legacy code) that suddenly started taking much longer time to execute. The only thing that has changed is that I've upgraded from SQL Server 2008 R2 Expr to SQL Server 2014 Expr and therefore started using SMO 2014.
I have a large number of databases, around 180, that I run through to try to find a number of them. The code that runs through them looks like this.

```
    foreach (Database db in instance.Databases)
    {
       foreach (FileGroup fileGroup in db.FileGroups)
       {
          foreach (DataFile dataFile in fileGroup.Files)
          {
          }
       }
    }
```

When I find the database I'm looking for the second foreach suddely takes a lot longer to execute, in worst cases up to a minute.
There is no code executing between the second and third foreach.
The code within the third foreach, where I do my stuff, executes fast as usual.

I cant figure out why this is taking so much longer. I've tried to find out if anything has changed in SMO in SQL Server 2014 that could cause this but I've had no luck.

If anyone could give me some idea about where to look I'd appreciate it.

*** UPDATE ***

This is the query made by SMO 2014 that, according to SQL Profiler, takes time. This query is not made when using SMO 2008 R2

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT
ISNULL((case dmi.mirroring_redo_queue_type when N''UNLIMITED'' then 0 else         
dmi.mirroring_redo_queue end),0) AS [MirroringRedoQueueMaxSize],
ISNULL(dmi.mirroring_connection_timeout,0) AS [MirroringTimeout],
ISNULL(dmi.mirroring_partner_name,'''') AS [MirroringPartner],
ISNULL(dmi.mirroring_partner_instance,'''') AS [MirroringPartnerInstance],
ISNULL(dmi.mirroring_role,0) AS [MirroringRole],
ISNULL(dmi.mirroring_safety_level + 1, 0) AS [MirroringSafetyLevel],
ISNULL(dmi.mirroring_state + 1, 0) AS [MirroringStatus],
ISNULL(dmi.mirroring_witness_name,'''') AS [MirroringWitness],
ISNULL(dmi.mirroring_witness_state + 1, 0) AS [MirroringWitnessStatus],
CAST(case when dmi.mirroring_partner_name is null then 0 else 1 end AS bit)         
AS [IsMirroringEnabled],
ISNULL(dmi.mirroring_guid,''00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000000000'') AS 
[MirroringID],
ISNULL(dmi.mirroring_role_sequence,0) AS [MirroringRoleSequence],
ISNULL(dmi.mirroring_safety_sequence,0) AS [MirroringSafetySequence],
ISNULL(dmi.mirroring_failover_lsn,0) AS 
[MirroringFailoverLogSequenceNumber],
dtb.is_ansi_null_default_on AS [AnsiNullDefault],
dtb.is_ansi_nulls_on AS [AnsiNullsEnabled],
dtb.is_ansi_padding_on AS [AnsiPaddingEnabled],
dtb.is_ansi_warnings_on AS [AnsiWarningsEnabled],
dtb.is_arithabort_on AS [ArithmeticAbortEnabled],
dtb.is_auto_shrink_on AS [AutoShrink],
dtb.is_cursor_close_on_commit_on AS [CloseCursorsOnCommitEnabled],
dtb.is_concat_null_yields_null_on AS [ConcatenateNullYieldsNull],
dtb.is_numeric_roundabort_on AS [NumericRoundAbortEnabled],
dtb.is_quoted_identifier_on AS [QuotedIdentifiersEnabled],
dtb.is_read_only AS [ReadOnly],
dtb.is_recursive_triggers_on AS [RecursiveTriggersEnabled],
dtb.is_local_cursor_default AS [LocalCursorsDefault],
dtb.page_verify_option AS [PageVerify],
dtb.recovery_model AS [RecoveryModel],
dtb.user_access AS [UserAccess],
dtb.is_db_chaining_on AS [DatabaseOwnershipChaining],
dtb.is_auto_update_stats_async_on AS [AutoUpdateStatisticsAsync],
dtb.is_date_correlation_on AS [DateCorrelationOptimization],
dtb.is_trustworthy_on AS [Trustworthy],
dtb.name AS [Name],
dtb.database_id AS [ID],
dtb.create_date AS [CreateDate],
dtb.is_auto_create_stats_on AS [AutoCreateStatisticsEnabled],
dtb.is_auto_update_stats_on AS [AutoUpdateStatisticsEnabled],
dtb.is_parameterization_forced AS [IsParameterizationForced],
dtb.is_read_committed_snapshot_on AS [IsReadCommittedSnapshotOn],
dtb.is_auto_close_on AS [AutoClose],
dtb.is_broker_enabled AS [BrokerEnabled],
CAST(isnull(dtb.source_database_id, 0) AS bit) AS [IsDatabaseSnapshot],
ISNULL(DB_NAME(dtb.source_database_id), N'''') AS 
[DatabaseSnapshotBaseName],
dtb.is_fulltext_enabled AS [IsFullTextEnabled],
dtb.service_broker_guid AS [ServiceBrokerGuid],
dtb.snapshot_isolation_state AS [SnapshotIsolationState],
(dtb.is_published*1+dtb.is_subscribed*2+dtb.is_merge_published*4) AS 
[ReplicationOptions],
ISNULL(suser_sname(dtb.owner_sid),'''') AS [Owner],
ISNULL(dtb.log_reuse_wait,0) AS [LogReuseWaitStatus],
drs.recovery_fork_guid AS [RecoveryForkGuid],
drs.database_guid AS [DatabaseGuid],
CAST((case when drs.last_log_backup_lsn is not null then 1 else 0 end) AS 
bit) AS [HasFullBackup],
CAST(case when dtb.name in (''master'',''model'',''msdb'',''tempdb'') then 1 
else dtb.is_distributor end AS bit) AS [IsSystemObject],
CAST(case when ctb.database_id is null then 0 else 1  end AS bit) AS 
[ChangeTrackingEnabled],
CAST(ISNULL(ctb.is_auto_cleanup_on,0) AS bit) AS 
[ChangeTrackingAutoCleanUp],
ISNULL(ctb.retention_period,0) AS [ChangeTrackingRetentionPeriod],
CAST(ISNULL(ctb.retention_period_units,0) AS tinyint) AS 
[ChangeTrackingRetentionPeriodUnits],
dtb.containment AS [ContainmentType],
dtb.default_language_lcid AS [DefaultLanguageLcid],
dtb.default_language_name AS [DefaultLanguageName],
dtb.default_fulltext_language_lcid AS [DefaultFullTextLanguageLcid],
ISNULL(dtb.default_fulltext_language_name,N'''') AS 
[DefaultFullTextLanguageName],
CAST(dtb.is_nested_triggers_on AS bit) AS [NestedTriggersEnabled],
CAST(dtb.is_transform_noise_words_on AS bit) AS [TransformNoiseWords],
dtb.two_digit_year_cutoff AS [TwoDigitYearCutoff],
dtb.target_recovery_time_in_seconds AS [TargetRecoveryTime],
dtb.delayed_durability AS [DelayedDurability],
dtb.is_auto_create_stats_incremental_on AS     
[AutoCreateIncrementalStatisticsEnabled],

          case
          when dtb.collation_name is null then 0x200
          else 0
          end |
          case
          when 1 = dtb.is_in_standby then 0x40
          else 0
          end |
          case dtb.state
          when 1 then 0x2 
          when 2 then 0x8
          when 3 then 0x4
          when 4 then 0x10
          when 5 then 0x100
          when 6 then 0x20
          else 1
          end
         AS [Status],
CAST(( case LOWER(convert( nvarchar(128), DATABASEPROPERTYEX(dtb.name, 
''Updateability''))) when ''read_write'' then 1 else 0 end) AS bit) AS 
[IsUpdateable],
CAST(dtb.is_encrypted AS bit) AS [EncryptionEnabled],
CAST(dtb.is_honor_broker_priority_on AS bit) AS [HonorBrokerPriority],
CAST(has_dbaccess(dtb.name) AS bit) AS [IsAccessible],
ISNULL(fsopt.directory_name , N'''') AS [FilestreamDirectoryName],
ISNULL(fsopt.non_transacted_access , 0) AS [FilestreamNonTransactedAccess],
dtb.name AS [DatabaseName2],
dtb.containment AS [ContainmentType2]
FROM
master.sys.databases AS dtb
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_mirroring AS dmi ON dmi.database_id = 
dtb.database_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_recovery_status AS drs ON drs.database_id = 
dtb.database_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.change_tracking_databases AS ctb ON ctb.database_id = 
dtb.database_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_filestream_options AS fsopt ON 
fsopt.database_id = dtb.database_id
WHERE
(dtb.name=@_msparam_0)',N'@_msparam_0 nvarchar(4000)',@_msparam_0=N'2016-11-
03'
```

Is this query something that has been added to SMO 2014?
Does anyone have an idea about why this is run?

Comment: Hook up a profiler and see what T-SQL is actually going to the server and if there's any delay executing those statements. In my experience, SMO can be surprisingly inefficient (as in, doing things you wouldn't expect from the code itself).

Comment: Followed your advise and ran a profiler. I found the query causing the time increase. It wasn't generated from my code but from SMO, at least as far as I can see. I updated my question with it.

Comment: That query just seems to retrieve basic info about a database in one convenient package. There's really no reason why that should take long at all, even when performed 180 times, as it's just querying some metadata. I have a server with 155 databases and this query takes 30 ms for one database. Is it doing this once per database or once per filegroup?

Comment: As shown in my first code piece, it goes through all databases, then all filegroups for each database and then each datafile in each file group. The query is executed for each datafile. The strange thing is that if I run this from the application it takes a long time with about 150 databses but when we ran it in SSMS with around 1000 databases it ran fast. From where I'm standing, SMO seems to be doing something funny.

Comment: While this is not an answer to your question, I've personally pretty much abandoned SMO except where it really adds value (like the `Scripter` class) and do the rest with SQL and PowerShell instead, where there are no hidden costs. For instance, while you're iterating over databases, you can get all files with a simple `SELECT f.* FROM [db].sys.filegroups g JOIN [db].sys.database_files f ON g.data_space_id = f.data_space_id`. While it's nice that SMO has a pre-packaged object model, for most tasks I'm fine abandoning this if it gets me a solution faster, and a faster solution.